# Data cleaning using pandas from excel file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to modify or clean the DataFrame to make it look like the picture added here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xoqt.png). I figured out how to remove the upper values (because the excel file is empty in the two first rows) but can not figure out how to remove the values from 5 and downwards as well. I have tried using the ***skiprows= range*** function, but I have already used this to skip the first rows in the excel file I have. In total I have 298 rows in the excel file, so I want to eliminate all the rows from 5 to 298 in the DataFrame.

The code I have used til know:

```
from pathlib import Path 
src_file = Path.cwd() /  'a1_data1.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(src_file, header=1, usecols='B', skiprows =
range(0,1)) 
df = np.round(df, 1)
df
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks
Adrian

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please show what you currently get when you print `df`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel(src_file, header=1, usecols='B', skiprows = range(0,1))
df = np.round(df, 1) 
df = df.head(5)
df
```

will do you, head(5) gives you the first 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

- For first Five Rows ([reference_for_first_five](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html))

```
df.head(5) # for First Five Rows
```

- For last Five Rows ([reference_for_last_five](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html))

```
df.tail(5) # for Last Five Rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:4,:], df.iloc[298:,:]], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

now you eliminate all the rows between from 5 to 298. I am not sure if you want to keep 5th one or not. so please tune it yourself.